# Xamarin error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: java, android, xamarin, nuget

I am getting this error after updating some NuGets
the project was working well and I have build it on debug and release many hundred times
I try setting Linking to None and Changing Code Shrinker and Dex complier clean the project delete bin and obj and changing java sdk location but everything doesn't work
I always getting

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.DX.targets(32,5
error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after following this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-save-and-configure-build-log-files?view=vs-2019
where I find this
xamarin com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzu is defined multiple times
so I install Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads directly to my project and it builds correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [MultiDexApplication](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/195239/#Comment_195239) class to your android project